# Is it possible to skip tests if an element doesn't exists?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm writing a test script for a website. The website has tabs (navigation link).

Let's say, the element of that tab is id=email.

If that doesn't exist, is it possible to skip the whole test. All test cases are based on that tab (id=email).

Right now, I have:

```
if($this->isElementPresent("id=email") == true) {
    perform these steps
}
```

And all the test scripts are like that, so it's just opening the browser and closing it without testing anything. It's passing them all. Is it possible to skip tests if that element doesn't exists?

Comment: if all test cases are based on that tab and you skip it, doesn't that mean you are skipping all tests...? then just do nothing!
And by the way, your code should work... have you even tried it? If yes, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I meant test cases. I have other test scripts that tests other features. I can turn on/off the feature, so it's no point running all the test cases if the feature doesn't exist. I don't get why I'm getting down voted. I'm asking a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would configure the test to use the same setting to see if the fields exist or not, instead of skipping tests.  Mock your configuration, and set to disabled, then the tests should look for the absence of the fields, and test accordingly.  Then, set the configuration to be enabled, and test that the field is there and test accordingly.

When the field is set to be disabled, you can also use the $this->markTestSkipped().  It is documented in the PHPUnit help [Chapter 9. Incomplete and Skipped Tests](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests).

Sample:

```
public function testEmailIdAbsent()
{
    if($this->MockConfiguration['Email'] == 'disabled')  // Or however your configuration looks
    {
         $this->assertFalse($Foo->IsElementPresent("id=email", "Email ID is present when disabled.");
        ...
    }
}

public function testEmailIdPresent()
{
    if($this->MockConfiguration['Email'] == 'enabled')  // Or however your configuration looks
    {
         $this->assertTrue($Foo->IsElementPresent("id=email", "Email ID is not present when enabled.");
        ...
    }
}

public function testEmailId()
{
    if($this->MockConfiguration['Email'] == 'disabled') // Or however your configuration looks
    {
        $this->markTestSkipped('Email configuration is disabled.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I haven't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why the message doesn't show when I put markTestSkipped?

Comment: @RaymondYan I think you have to run in verbose mode. Either set it in phpunit.xml.dist, or use `phpunit --verbose`

Comment: I believe you need verbose mode, as Darren Cook indicated.  I also use the field as a reminder for myself as to why the test is skipped, more so then seeing it on the output. I use the Incomplete and Skipped settings, so I know the incompletes need to be revisited, and the skipped are meant to be based on configurations.  However, we try to still not have the skipped tests since we can test both variations in isolation.  I mostly provided the example in case you wanted to use it.  Our tests tend not to have skipped tests. Test cases set the variable and test as the first 2 examples do.